# Moving cloned maps

Tags: mapinfo

Is it possible to always have exactly the same area of a map shown on the clone as on the original?

As I move around the original map, I want the cloned map to move automatically to show the same area.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize Windows Tool (MapInfo Professional 7.8 and higher).

[image]

> The Synchronize Windows tool provides toolbar icons that allow the
>   ability to automatically share changes made in one mapper window to
>   all other mapper windows in a given MapInfo Professional session

source:
http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/kbase_by_product/E54CAEF736F3E51D85256F1D00486088